# How do I make these controls NOT required?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

We've started refactoring some web forms to .NET6 (MVC C# Razor)

I am doing nothing that I am aware of to make my optional controls required, yet the browser is requiring them nonetheless. How can I make this control optional?

in the C# class:

```html
[Display(Name = "Web link for more info")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)] // I tried removing this but it makes no difference
public string MoreInfoURL { get; set; } = "";
```

in the Razor cshtml:

```html
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MoreInfoURL)
<span class="description">Web address to a page that provides more information for interested audiences</span>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MoreInfoURL, new {placeholder = "(optional)"})
```

the generated html

```html
<label for="MoreInfoURL">Web link for more info</label>
<span class="description">Web address to a page that provides more information for interested audiences</span>
<input data-val="true" id="MoreInfoURL" name="MoreInfoURL" placeholder="(optional)" type="text" value="">
```

The result: when I try to submit the form with this control empty, browser jumps up and highlights the control like it is requiring me to enter it - even though I've done nothing to make it required (they worked properly in the previous version of .NET)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nullable element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) configures how the compiler interprets the nullability of types and what warnings are emitted. enable means Non-nullable unless declared with ?.Here are two solutions:

1.Remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in .csproj file and remove `Required` attribute.
[image]

2.Try to add `?` to `MoreInfoURL` and remove `Required` attribute.

```
[Display(Name = "Web link for more info")]
public string? MoreInfoURL { get; set; } = "";
```

Comment: Altering <PropertyGroup> had no affect. Making the string nullable worked though. In previous versions this was treated like an empty string, but this makes sense. Thank you.